# Replace default loading screen image with custom animation

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer, lottie

I made an android application using the kivy framework. I noticed that in the buildozer.spec file; There are lines that suggest the possibility of **implementing an animation to replace the default loading screen**.

The lines I'm talking about are...

```
# (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
# see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
# for general documentation.
# Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
#android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"
```

I want to reference a **lottie animation** from the **buildozer.spec** file. In order to **replace** the **default loading screen image** with a **custom loading animation**.

The app is already finished. I am in the compilation phase with buildozer. The method I'm using is...

**1.** Load **the modules** and **the lottie .json animation** into an instance of [**THIS COLAB NOTEBOOK**](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1b9gMzs6XAtxCtahxei4N0fWZk7xiPlVw?usp=sharing).

**2.** Run the cells up to the code cell that contains the `!buildozer init` command.

**3.** Modify the **buildozer.spec** file to reference my **.json extension animation**.

The modification I make is specifically on line 89 of the buildozer.spec file:

From...

```
#android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"
```

To...

```
android.presplash_lottie = "loading.json"
```

**#Note:** Below I show some alternative examples of ways in which I tried to modify the file with similar results.

**4.** Once this modification is done, I continue with the execution of the following code cell: `!buildozer -v android debug`. Once the execution is finished I receive the following error message:

```
[INFO]:    COMMAND:
cd /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp && /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp/gradlew assembleDebug

[WARNING]: ERROR: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp/gradlew failed!
WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Applying Java source code patches...
Applying patch: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --bootstrap sdl2 --dist_name myapp --name 'My Application' --version 0.1 --package org.test.myapp --minsdk 21 --ndk-api 21 --private /content/.buildozer/android/app --android-entrypoint org.kivy.android.PythonActivity --android-apptheme @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar --presplash-lottie /content/"loading.json" --orientation portrait --window --copy-libs --arch arm64-v8a --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir="/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     CUDNN_VERSION = '8.0.5.39'
#     PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL = 'NO'
#     LD_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64'
#     CLOUDSDK_PYTHON = 'python3'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     ENABLE_DIRECTORYPREFETCHER = '1'
#     HOSTNAME = '4e5cfbd61f47'
#     OLDPWD = '/'
#     CLOUDSDK_CONFIG = '/content/.config'
#     USE_AUTH_EPHEM = '1'
#     NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 'all'
#     DATALAB_SETTINGS_OVERRIDES = '{"kernelManagerProxyPort":6000,"kernelManagerProxyHost":"172.28.0.3","jupyterArgs":["--ip=172.28.0.2"],"debugAdapterMultiplexerPath":"/usr/local/bin/dap_multiplexer","enableLsp":true}'
#     ENV = '/root/.bashrc'
#     PAGER = 'cat'
#     NCCL_VERSION = '2.7.8'
#     TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH = 'true'
#     JPY_PARENT_PID = '45'
#     NO_GCE_CHECK = 'False'
#     PWD = '/content'
#     HOME = '/root'
#     LAST_FORCED_REBUILD = '20220726'
#     CLICOLOR = '1'
#     DEBIAN_FRONTEND = 'noninteractive'
#     LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs'
#     GCE_METADATA_TIMEOUT = '3'
#     GLIBCPP_FORCE_NEW = '1'
#     TBE_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8008'
#     TERM = 'xterm-color'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     GCS_READ_CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_MB = '16'
#     PYTHONWARNINGS = 'ignore:::pip._internal.cli.base_command'
#     MPLBACKEND = 'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
#     CUDA_VERSION = '11.1.1'
#     NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES = 'compute,utility'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     PYTHONPATH = '/env/python'
#     NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA = ('cuda>=11.1 brand=tesla,driver>=418,driver<419 '
 'brand=tesla,driver>=440,driver<441 brand=tesla,driver>=450,driver<451')
#     TBE_EPHEM_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8009'
#     COLAB_GPU = '0'
#     GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW = '1'
#     PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/tools/node/bin:/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin'
#     LD_PRELOAD = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc.so.4'
#     GIT_PAGER = 'cat'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r23b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I know that the problem lies in the modification that I made in the buildozer.spec file because when I do the same process skipping this step, the apk file is generated correctly.

That's the problem. That said, I proceed to declare information that may be useful to anyone who wants to help me with this.

---

### Hello world in kivy

(So ​​you don't have to write or search one)

**main.py**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello World')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

---

### Free example .json animation in lottie

[Loading animation](https://lottiefiles.com/98993-three-dots-loading)

---

### List of solutions that I tried but that do not work

1. Replace **line 89 of buildozer.spec** with

   `android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/loading.json"`
2. Replace **it** with

   `android.presplash_lottie = "loading.json"`
3. Replace **it** with

   `android.presplash_lottie = "/content/loading.json"`
4. Replace **it** with

   `android.presplash_lottie = %(source.dir)s/data/loading.json`
5. Add **json** to

   `source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas`

---

Thanks in advance!
Hope it's useful.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to edit buildozer.spec for successfully implementing lottie animation in kivy app:
1)line 89: android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"

2)line 102:Android.api = set to max level as per latest android api

3)line 105:android.minapi = 28(reason:lottie files don't work below android api 28)

4)line 195:android.enable_androidx = True

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ellhe-blaster is this edit much better than before?

Answer (score 0):

Make below changes!!

1. Add **json** to the list:

`source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,json`

2. Add **assets/*.json** to the list:

`source.include_patterns = assets/*.txt,assets/*.json,assets/*.kv,data/*.png`

3. Define path in the line:

`android.presplash_lottie = "assets/lottie.json"`

All done!!

Answer (score 0):

For using a Lottie File in Kivy/KivyMD App as presplash screen, just make these following changes in your `Buildozer.specs` file and you are good to go.

1. Add **`json`** to the list:

`source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,json`

2. Change Your target API Version to something higher like `33`. Latest for Android 13. Uncomment the line and then change it.

`android.api = 33`

3. Change your min API Version to `28`. Lottie files are supported only on API greater than or equal to 28. Uncomment the line and then change it:

`android.minapi = 28`

4. Then find the line stating, **Enable AndroidX support**. It will be available in line `209`. But this might change in the future. There uncomment the following line:

`android.enable_androidx = True`

5. Now Upload your lottie json file in the Google Colab Directory or the directory in which your main python file is if you are on Linux. Uncomment and change the path of your lottie file to the following line:

`android.presplash_lottie = %(source.dir)s/lottie.json`